# Model field containing both DecimalField and a CharField

Tags: django-models, django-views

I have an Ingredient class where each object has different values of nutrients (e.g. Zinc, Magnesium, Protein etc.). Further, each nutrient has a different unit (e.g. mg, g, kg etc.). This unit of the nutrient may depend on the ingredient, so for some ingredients Zinc is in mg and others in μg. The view of the ingredients fetches all the nutrients of that ingredient, and I don't want too many database fetches.

How do I achieve this in a smart manner?

*I've tried:*

- Making two variables in the model class for each nutrient (value and unit). This is a lot of code, though, and seems redundant
- Making a MicroNutrient and a NutrientValue model classes, where the latter has the former and Ingredient as foreign keys. This produces a lot of database fetches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [choice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices) as *UOM*(unit of measurements) field and value field in your **Nutrient** model.
Then you can make **Ingredient** as foreign key for **Nutrient** model.

For the fetch, use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related), example:

```
result = Ingredient.objects.select_related('nutrient')
```

This produce less database fetch, from django documentation:

> Returns a QuerySet that will “follow” foreign-key relationships,
> selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query.
> This is a performance booster which results in a single more complex
> query but means later use of foreign-key relationships won’t require
> database queries.

```
# Hits the database with joins to the author and hometown tables.
b = Book.objects.select_related("author__hometown").get(id=4)
p = b.author  # Doesn't hit the database.
c = p.hometown  # Doesn't hit the database.

# Without select_related()...
b = Book.objects.get(id=4)  # Hits the database.
p = b.author  # Hits the database.
c = p.hometown  # Hits the database.
```